# Make a call using PhpSIP class

Tags: php, sip, voip

I'm trying to create a click-to-call button on a web page.
I've found and used this: https://code.google.com/p/php-sip/.

It works, in sense of it I can call a number in my AsteriskPBX, it rings, but when I answer it's no sound.
I tottaly understand that php-sip class can't handle audio stream, but how can i provide a sound streaming between users?

Answer (score 0):

First sentence on that page;

"This is a PHP implementation of a simple SIP user agent (UAS / UAC). PHP SIP is not a VoIP phone. It is not possible to make "voip calls" with this tool - only SIP signalling is supported - **no audio available**."

You should look into a different language to handle connecting users using audio, such as HTML5 or Flash.